# SAS, sum by row AND column

Tags: sas

I want to do some sum calculate for a data set. The challenge is I need to do both row sum AND column Sum by ID. Below is the example.

```
data have;
input ID var1 var2;
datalines;

1 1 1 
1 3 2 
1 2 3 
2 0 5 
2 1 3 
3 0 1 
;
run;

data want;
input ID var1 var2 sum;
datalines;

1 1 1 12
1 3 2 12
1 2 3 12
2 0 5 9
2 1 3 9
3 0 1 1
;
run;
```

Comment: Please remember to include what you've attempted so far. This is really similar to your previous question so you should have a good start at it at least.

Comment: This kind of question begs a *why* ?  Perhaps a `Proc REPORT` or `Proc TABULATE` can be a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL to do all of it in one step. Group only by `ID`, but keep `var1` and `var2` in the column selection. This will create the same data in `want`.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
        select ID
             , var1
             , var2
             , sum(var1) + sum(var2) as sum
        from have
        group by ID
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL is cool, but SAS has nice data step!

```
proc sort data=have; by id; run;
data result;
   set have;
   by id;
   retain sum 0;
   if first.id then sum=0;
   sum=sum+sum(var1,var2);
   if last.id then output;
run;

proc sort data=result; by id; run;
data want;
   merge have result;
   by id;
run;
```

You will decide what to use...